# Error: Could not find or load main class RectangleApplication when adding a jar to classpath

Tags: java, cygwin, classpath

I need some help with a really trivial problem which i cannot get to work. So i create a simple java project with two files. RectangleApplication.java and AreaCalculator.java (in the same src folder). Then I compile them with javac *.java. Then i create a jar file for AreaCalculator.class and removes the AreaCalculator.class from the src folder. If i now execute

"java Main", i will get a ClassNotFoundException which i was expecting. What i was not expecting was to get a "could not find or load main class RectangleApplication when i ran the command

`java -cp .:area-calculator.jar RectangleApplication`

Can someone please explain to me what i am doing wrong. I have tried everything, but when i add a runtime classpath to find my jar, it will not find my Main class.

Comment: This suggests that locations from classpath don't contain `RectangleApplication.class` file. From your description of creating JAR "*Then i create a jar file for AreaCalculator.class and removes the AreaCalculator.class from the src folder.*" you are only mentioning `AreaCalculator`. Is it possible that you forgot to put `RectangleApplication` there, but still deleted it?

Comment: What i want to do is to create a jar that only has my AreaCalculator.class file. This is for testing if i can add a jar package to my classpath when i run RectangleApplication.class. This means that if i am in the src folder(where i still have my main class(RectangleApplication) i should be able to find this class with "." and then i should be able to add my jar(area-calculator.jar) to my classpath and run. But i cannot make it work. Does this help you more? This means that i don't want to have RectangleApplication.class in my jar file.

Comment: I have found out something else. It works in my Windows Command Prompt, but not i my CygWin Terminal Window. Does someone know why?

Comment: I am not CygWin user so I can't help you here. Consider updating your question with that new information and also add to it `cygwin` tag so specialist observing that tag would see your question.

Comment: Oh, to update your question simply use [edit] option below it.